# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] not working in echo

Tags: php

I am wondering why is that the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not working in my code in `echo` with `html option tag`?

This is my sample:

```
echo "<option value='".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."'/acces/login/validate?employee=".$login->employee()."&password=".$login->get_pwd()."'>LOGIN</option>";
```

Comment: Define "not working". What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Variables may not exist or may not contain the value you expect, but they can't "not work".

Answer (score 4):

It's generally a bad idea to reveal your document root, especially as there is no need for it in the browser. That aside, though, you should always look at the rendered HTML:

```
<option value='/path/to/doc/root'/acces/login/validate?employee=steve
                                 &password=use plaintext and die'>LOGIN</option>
```

(Line wrap added to avoid ugly horizontal scrollbar)

See that extra `'` after the doc root? That'll be your problem.